# Unbind from an event in a handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using iScroll to automatically scroll every time an input comes into focus. However, on android, the blue pointer stays frozen as document scrolls. So I need to unfocus from element, scroll, then focus again without calling handler.

I have a function to listen for when all inputs and future inputs come into focus.

```
    this.inputFocusListener = function () {
        var self = this;

        $(document).on("focus", "input", this.bindFocusHandler.bind(this));

    },
```

I use `.bind(this)` above to change the context of this as there are other methods in the parent I will call in the handler.

Once in the handler, I want to unbind from the handler, then call blur() to unfocus from input element, I then automatically scroll up for down, then focus again after scroll but without calling handler:

```
   this.bindFocusHandler = function (e) {


           $(e.currentTarget).off('focus...');
           $(e.currentTarget).blur();

           ....scroll up/down...

           //now focus again on the input without calling handler
           $(e.currentTarget).focus();

   },
```

But when I call focus again, I enter an infinte loop because I cannot unbind from the focus event for that element...

Comment: You just bound the focus event to the document, why would it be removed when you call off() on an element ?

Comment: first why are you calling `.focus()` from an focus handler?

Comment: It's unclear why you are using `.bind()` and `e.currentTarget` anyway. That's completely unnecessary with jQuery. Also, please explain why you you want to unbind the event handler in the first place.

Comment: if you still want to use it then call `$e.currentTarget.focus();` instead of `$(e.currentTarget).focus();` so that the handler will not get executed...

Comment: Just do `$(document).one("focus", "input", this.bindFocusHandler.bind(this));` instead ?

Comment: your `.off()` does not work because the event handler is bound to the document object not to the `e.currentTarget`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think you left a `$` behind as you must have meant `e.currentTarget.focus();` instead of `$e.currentTarget.focus();`

Comment: @gillesc yes... missed that

Comment: just edited the question to clear things up...